# Image not becoming a hyperlink

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

i have got this picture button on my site and i am trying to link it to another page using this code but it is not working at all :)
Here is the code. PLease help.

```
<a href="###"></a><img src="###" width="254" height="45"/>
```

Comment: I love how we all put ~identical answers within a few seconds... %^O

Comment: Please complete a basic HTML tutorial at least, before asking questions here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

The `<img>` part should be within the `<a>` tags...

```
<a href="###"><img src="###" width="254" height="45"/></a>
```

Basic HTML rules are that the link is what falls between the opening and closing `<a>` tags, whether text or image.

Answer (score 1):

You want it as this:

```
<a href="###"><img src="###" alt="alt text"></a>
```

The width and height tags are deprecated as you should use CSS for them, but the alt tag is required for HTML5 validation.

Answer (score 1):

Having img tag within a tag says that associate a link to my image and show the image once clicked. You can also add "target=_blank" to open your image in new tab.

```
### would be the link 

<a href="###">
<img src="###" alt="my image" width="254" height="45" target="_blank" />
</a>
```

Learn more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML)

Comment: Please don't point beginners to w3schools. They better not learn from there.

Comment: @kapa why is that? I believe its a great site where even I started to learn stuff

Comment: It is a poor quality site. I started to learn stuff there but regretted a thousand times. They masquerade themselves as something official, like they have something to do with w3c. They spread bad practices. Avoid. MDN is a great resource for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want image to be linkable, you need to place img tag inside the anchor tag

```
<a href="linkhere"><img src="img source" /></a>
```